# Saber diferencia de tiempo en consulta mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tengo una tabla en mysql para ver los accesos erróneos de un login.
Si hay 3 registros en menos de 60 minutos quiero poder bloquear el acceso a la dirección ip que esta intentando entrar.
En la base de datos guardo 2 campos:
ip: formato varchar 
hora: formato timestamp

La idea es hacer una consulta a mysql que me devuelva todos los registros donde la misma ip tenga una diferencia de tiempo respecto a la hora actual que sea de 60 minutos.

No tengo ni idea de por donde empezar. Mirando el manual de referencia de mysql veo esta función

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');
        -> 128885
```

Pero no se muy bien que datos ponerle o si es eso lo que necesito.

¿Como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Sí es timestamp podría ser `SELECT COUNT(*) 
from mitabla 
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, nombrecolumnafecha ,now()) < 60`   retornará la cantidad de registros que tengan la diferencia en minutos sea menor a 60 , me comenta si es lo que desea 3:)

Comment: Pues apunta maneras que si es lo que necesito. voy a probar a ver que responde y te digo

Comment: En principio parece que si...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si desea calcular la diferencia de  tiempo en minutos usando la  función [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) es correcta la sintaxis que está adoptando. Los parámetros que acepta es

1. Unidad de Tiempo para calcular la diferencia como `MONTH`, `YEAR`, `MINUTE`
2. La fecha de su tabla en su base de datos que desea comparar
3. La Fecha Actual que se puede obtener con `now()` *(tener en cuenta la zona horaria de la bd )*

*Ojo que si invierte los parámetros 2 y 3 obtendrá posiblemente valores negativos.*

Entonces su consulta puede quedar de la siguiente forma.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from mitabla where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, nombrecolumnafecha ,now()) < 60
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a330b7/2)</kbd>